# Name validation - Adding a check to this regex to stop entering just identical characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to add another feature to a regex which is trying to validate names (first or last).

At the moment it looks like this:

/^(?!^mr$|^mrs$|^ms$|^miss$|^dr$|^mr-mrs$)([a-z][a-z'-]{1,})$/i

https://regex101.com/r/pQ1tP2/1

The idea is to do the following

- Don't allow just adding a title like Mr, Mrs etc
- Ensure the first character is a letter
- Ensure subsequent characters are either letters, hyphens or apostrophes
- Minimum of two characters

I have managed to get this far (shockingly I find regex so confusing lol).

It matches things like O'Brian or Anne-Marie etc and is doing a pretty good job.

My next additions I've struggled with though! trying to add additional features to the regex to not match on the following:

- Just entering the same characters i.e. aaa bbbbb etc

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd add another negative lookahead alternative matching against `^(.)\1*$`, that is, any character, repetead until the end of the string.
Included as is in your regex, it would make that :

```
/^(?!^mr$|^mrs$|^ms$|^miss$|^dr$|^mr-mrs$|^(.)\1*$)([a-z][a-z'-]{1,})$/i
```

However, I would probably simplify your negative lookahead as follows :

```
/^(?!(mr|ms|miss|dr|mr-mrs|(.)\2*)$)([a-z][a-z'-]{1,})$/i
```

The modifications are as follow :

- We're evaluating the lookahead at the start of the string, as indicated by the `^` preceding it : no need to repeat that we match the start of the string in its clauses
- Each alternative match the end of the string. We can put the alternatives in a group, which will be followed by the end-of-string anchor
- We have created a new group, which we have to take into account in our back-reference : to reference the same group, it now must address `\2` rather than `\1`. An alternative in certain regex flavours would have been to use a non-capturing group `(?:...)`